# cross domain fb Login in ie9

Tags: facebook

I am using ie9 for facebook login with corss domain. I am facing the fb user id issue, It's not getting the fb user id.. so the whole code is not working properyly. can any one help me ASAP. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- Ensure your server has a p3p header in each response. See: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx
- Ensure you have the link to your ChannelUrl specified in your FB.init() call, and that that file reside on the same domain as your code that is running. See: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/530/

Comment: It's your server and your code, I couldn't even know since I don't have rights to your server to see what you have there.